# How to get the timestamp range of this hour?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

How to get the UNIX timestamp range of the current hour, i mean one of the first second and the other for the last second. so if it's 18:45 i would get the timestamp of 18:00 and 18:59.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the components of the current time with `getdate()`, and use `mktime()` to find the timestamps:

```
$date = getdate();
$start = mktime($date['hours'], 0, 0);
$end = $start + (60*60);
```

You can also use `date()`, which is slightly simpler:

```
$start = mktime(date("H"), 0, 0);
$end = $start + (60*60);
```

Comment: To truly get the *last second* you should add `(60 * 60) - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = mktime(date('H'), 0, 0);
$end = mktime(date('H'), 59, 59);
```

Could be generalized for any timestamp, not just the current time, as:

```
$time = time(); // some timestamp
$start = mktime(date('H', $time), 0, 0, date('n', $time), date('j', $time), date('Y', $time));
$end = mktime(date('H', $time), 59, 59, date('n', $time), date('j', $time), date('Y', $time));
```